# What game is this screenshot featuring a girl sitting on the beach from?

Tags: game-identification

Does anybody know where this screenshot is from?

[image]

It features a girl sitting on the sand at a beach.

Comment: Where did you get this image? At least the icons / UI is sorta distinct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the icons, it appears to be [Oasis - Start your second life](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasis.world&gl=US), a game for Android.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Oasis' beach with]

Comment: Wow! How did you find it?

Comment: @Malady Google reverse image search, I tried to focus on the buttons layout